# Reindex problem catalog_category_product_index_store10_replica

Tags: reindex

Recently I've been facing issues with reindex process, some indexes are shown with status **Reindex Required** and even if I achieve to reindex them they continue with the same status.
[image]

After some days indexes got stuck and reindex never ends.

So I decided to take a backup from my production server and investigate deeper but when I run mysqldump I get and error because **catalog_category_product_index_store10_replica** table is always busy.

And if I query the amount of records on this table many times just with few seconds one after each other I got different results.

`select count(*) from catalog_category_product_index_store10_replica;`

Example

- Second 1 -> 1288
- Second 2 -> 722
- Second 4 -> 0

It seems like there is a process stuck or something is being executed over and over, do you have any idea about this?

Comment: Can you please check into your admin, do you have any store created and which id is 10?

Comment: Yes, I have one store with id 10

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following things.

1. Stop all the indexing by CLI.
2. `catalog_category_product_index_store10_replica` empty this table.
3. Enable All the indexing by CLI.